# Prevent default.aspx addition

Tags: iis, iis-6

How can I prevent browsers to add `portal/default.aspx` to my url string?

Comment: so where is the question, then?

Comment: what's the problem with the question? I have IIS 6 hosted website and when you type in an addressbar http://mysite.com/ browser loads http://mysite.com/portal/default.aspx instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem. It seems that browsers change URI because of "Server: Microsoft IIS 6" header. All started to work normally after I've got rid of it (via URLScan tool)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the default document in IIS Admin as described here:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true